# Why is collections.deque slower than collections.defaultdict?

Tags: python, performance, spell-checking, deque, defaultdict

Forgive me for asking in in such a general way as I'm sure their performance is depending on how one uses them, but in my case `collections.deque` was way slower than `collections.defaultdict` when I wanted to verify the existence of a value.

I used the [spelling correction from Peter Norvig](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) in order to verify a user's input against a small set of words. As I had no use for a dictionary with word frequencies I used a simple `list` instead of `defaultdict` at first, but replaced it with `deque` as soon as I noticed that a single word lookup took about 25 seconds.

Surprisingly, that wasn't faster than using a `list` so I returned to using `defaultdict` which returned results almost instantaneously.

Can someone explain this difference in performance to me?

Thanks in advance

---

*PS*: If one of you wants to reproduce what I was talking about, change the following lines in Norvig's script.

```
-NWORDS = train(words(file('big.txt').read()))
+NWORDS = collections.deque(words(file('big.txt').read()))

-return max(candidates, key=NWORDS.get)
+return candidates
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These three data structures aren't interchangeable, they serve very different purposes and have very different characteristics:

- Lists are dynamic arrays, you use them to store items sequentially for fast random access, use as stack (adding and removing at the end) or just storing something and later iterating over it in the same order.
- Deques are sequences too, only for adding and removing elements at both ends instead of random access or stack-like growth.
- Dictionaries (providing a default value just a relatively simple and convenient but - for this question - irrelevant extension) are hash tables, they associate fully-featured keys (instead of an index) with values and provide very fast access to a value by a key and (necessarily) very fast checks for key existence. They don't maintain order and require the keys to be hashable, but well, you can't make an omelette without breaking eggs.

All of these properties are important, keep them in mind whenever you choose one over the other. What breaks your neck in this particular case is a combination of the last property of dictionaries and the number of possible corrections that have to be checked. Some simple combinatorics should arrive at a concrete formula for the number of edits this code generates for a given word, but everyone who mispredicted such things often enough will know it's going to be surprisingly large number even for average words.

For *each* of these edits, there is a check `edit in NWORDS` to weeds out edits that result in unknown words. Not a bit problem in Norvig's program, since `in` checks (key existence checks) are, as metioned before, very fast. But you swaped the dictionary with a sequence (a deque)! For sequences, `in` has to iterate over the whole sequence and compare each item with the value searched for (it can stop when it finds a match, but since the least edits are know words sitting at the beginning of the deque, it usually still searches all or most of the deque). Since there are quite a few words and the test is done for each edit generated, you end up spending 99% of your time doing a linear search in a sequence where you could just hash a string and compare it once (or at most - in case of collisions - a few times).

If you don't need weights, you can conceptually use bogus values you never look at and still get the performance boost of an O(1) `in` check. Practically, you should just use a `set` which uses pretty much the same algorithms as the dictionaries and just cuts away the part where it stores the value (it was actually first implemented like that, I don't know how far the two diverged since sets were re-implemented in a dedicated, seperate C module).

Comment: Thank you very much for this in depth answer.